# How Azure Application gateway is using for multitenant Application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway

Here We want to redirect application gateway to https we don't want to manually enter https to get on SSL.
We use the gateway for fabric we want all application on fabric using SSL.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: We are actually working on Gateway we configured the gateway on SSL, for accessing gateway we can manually enter https instead of entering it we want to redirect it from HTTP to https.

Backend of Gateway we use Fabric Application for SSL offload